# linux bash cp different file from different folder

Tags: linux, bash

I have 100 folders name from 0, 0.1 ...to 10, and the file in side the folder is  name U, then I want copy it to other folder, but have also the same name folder 0, 0.1,...10. and each file will paste at each folder. How to write this bash script.

```
N = 100
startime = 0
 for i in $(seq 1 $N)
do
cp path1 //the file that i want to copy form folder 0 0.1 ...10)// path2 //the folder that i want to paste in folder 0 0.1 ...10//

//Specify startTime to solve, endTime should be changed to startTime function in controlDict

done
```

Comment: Use `bc` to divide `$i` by 10 (since `bash` doesn't have floating point built-in). Then use that in the folder name when copying.

Comment: check your code at https://shellcheck.net and update your question with the corrected code. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you provided was only a **partial** pseudo-code for your intended script, along with some description of functional specification.

What is a script containing actual code to show that you did apply some effort at choosing/formulating the code to fit your application, thereby showing som implicit requirements not otherwise specified.

Nonetheless, I created the following based on what you provided.

```
#!/bin/bash

frDIR=$(pwd)/src
toDIR=$(pwd)/dst

N=100
startime=0

mkdir -p "${frDIR}"
mkdir -p "${toDIR}"

### PHASE I - create dummy input for demo
index=${startime}

while [ ${index} -le ${N} ]
do
    dirLABEL=$( echo "${index}" | awk -v divisor=10 '{ printf("%0.1f\n", $0/divisor ) ; }' )
    mkdir -p "${frDIR}/${dirLABEL}"

    echo "dummy" > "${frDIR}/${dirLABEL}/U"
    index=$((index+=1))
done

ls -ltr ${frDIR}/*

echo -e "\n Hit return to continue ..." ; read k

### PHASE II - copy files from src directory structure into dst directory structure
index=${startime}

while [ ${index} -le ${N} ]
do
    dirLABEL=$( echo "${index}" | awk -v divisor=10 '{ printf("%0.1f\n", $0/divisor ) ; }' )
    mkdir -pv "${toDIR}/${dirLABEL}"

    cp -pv "${frDIR}/${dirLABEL}/U" "${toDIR}/${dirLABEL}"
    echo ""
    index=$((index+=1))
done

echo -e "\n Hit return to continue ..." ; read k

ls -ltr ${toDIR}/*
```